# MongoDB Aggregration - $match inside of nested Schema as array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, aggregation

I would like to use $sum operation inside an aggregate operation of mongoDB. However, there is a field inside the nested Schema which is a also array I have to check.

This is my top schema Cart :

```js
const CartSchema = new Schema({
    created_at: { type: Date, default: moment() },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: moment(), expires: 300 },
    cartitems: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'cartitem'}],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
});
```

And this is the CartItemSchema :

```js
const CartItemSchema = new Schema({
    cart : {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'cart'
    },
    product : {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'product'
    },
    created_at : { type : Date, default : moment() },
    quantity : Number
});
```

And this is my aggregation function :

```js
CartSchema.statics.findStockFromCarts = function (productId) {

    return this.aggregate([
        { $unwind : "$cartitems" },
        { $match : { "cartitems" : { "product" :{  "$oid" : productId } } }},
        {
            $group: {   
                "_id" : "$oid",
                total: {
                    $sum: "cartitems.quantity",                    
                }
            }
        }
    ])

}
```

The actual behavior is that it returns an empty array.

The expected behavior is that it has to return total quantity of the products who are in those carts.

Result from the mLab :

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a7a2ac99f12ff0874be3e0c"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-02-06T22:22:47.913Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2018-02-06T22:23:05.779Z"
    },
    "cartitems": [
        {
            "created_at": {
                "$date": "2018-02-06T22:22:47.915Z"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a7a2aca9f12ff0874be3e0d"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "product": {
                "$oid": "5a76449c852bcd2427911fba"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}
```

The query for creating this document !

```js
CartSchema.statics.addItem = function (cartId, productId, quantity) {
    console.log("CartSchema addItem : cartId : " + cartId);
    console.log("CartSchema addItem : item : " + productId);
    console.log("CartSchema addItem : quantity : " + quantity);
    const CartItem = mongoose.model('cartitem');
    return this.findById(cartId)
        .then(cart => {
            const cartitem = new CartItem({ quantity });
            cartitem.product = productId;
            console.log("CartSchema addItem : cartItem : " + cartitem);
            console.log("CartSchema addItem : cartItem.id " + cartitem.id)
            cart.cartitems.push(cartitem);
            console.log("CartSchema addItem : cart total : " + cart)
            return Promise.all([
                cart.save()
            ]).then(([cart]) => cart);
        })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to populate the cart items before applying match condition.

`$lookup` stage is used to pull data from cart items collection based on matching cartitems array followed by `$unwind` and `$match` to provide query criteria for matching products.

`$group` stage to sum to output quantity total.

```
this.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"cartitems", // name of the collection, not model or schema name
  "localField":"cartitems",
  "foreignField":"_id",
  "as":"cartitems"
}},
{"$unwind":"$cartitems"},
{"$match":{"cartitems.product":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId)}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id",
  "total":{"$sum":"$cartitems.quantity"}
}}])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tested your answer and it returns an empty array too. Do you want me to share the document from mLab ?

Comment: Np. Yes please.

Comment: so how did you produce the document that you just posted ? Is it possible to get two separate documents from each collection ? Can I see your query ?

Comment: Can you please check again ?

Comment: Do you get any output when you run the query without group and match ?

Comment: I tried that and returns an empty array too.
return this.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "cartitems", // name of the collection, not model or schema name
                "localField": "cartitems",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "cartitems"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$cartitems" },
    ])

Comment: Sorry I meant your query.Try `this.aggregate([
        { $unwind : "$cartitems" }])` and let me know. You dont need the lookup as it looks you only have one collection. I was confused with the way you've set up the schema.

Comment: Cart stock : [{"_id":"5a7a2deb003a5e0906617039","created_at":"2018-02-06T22:36:24.751Z","updated_at":"2018-02-06T22:36:27.350Z","cartitems":{"created_at":"2018-02-06T22:36:24.752Z","_id":"5a7a2deb003a5e090661703a","quantity":1,"product":"5a76449c852bcd2427911fba"},"__v":1}]

Comment: I have succeeded getting the sum but I could not manage to use $match for finding the productId equalization

Comment: Cart stock : [{"_id":"5a7a2e68f5454e0922569fb9","total":1}]

There we go. Thank you so much, sir ! You made my day :)